# Need suggestions for using HTML 5 based chart components for my webapp

Tags: html, extjs, fusioncharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to provide charts on the web? Server-side or client-side library? HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305052/best-way-to-provide-charts-on-the-web-server-side-or-client-side-library-html5)

we have a Webapp which has its presentation layer built on Flex. This website consists of pages which have flex charts on them like a Barchart, Column chart, Piechart, etc. Since we want this website to work on iPads and iPhones we are planning to move the presentation layer to HTML5. Our charts are represented on a dashboard inside a portlet which are draggable and our click interactive. I have heard some names like Fusion charts and Senchas. What others 3rd party charts can i use?

Comment: There's a good answer to a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305052/best-way-to-provide-charts-on-the-web-server-side-or-client-side-library-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the course of two years I've migrated tens of my clients to JavaScript charts from Flash. There are a lot of good charting libraries for Flash, but when it comes to HTML5/JavaScript it basically comes down to two choices:

[amCharts JavaScript Charts](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/) and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

They're both are packed with features, actively developed and supported. I suggest you download both of them (they offer fully functional free versions) and try whichever suits your tasks better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com).